# Is Side-Side-Angle a valid congruency pattern for triangles sharing that first side?

Tags: geometry

The image below shows two triangles. I am convinced that this is a Side-Side-Angle situation, which is not enough to prove the two triangles  congruent. Is this correct?

What is throwing me off is that the triangles share a common side.

[image]

Comment: if $|NP|>|PM|$ then they are congruent, according to the [definition of the SSA congruency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH94J.png).

Comment: Don't angles opposite congruent sides have to be congruent as well?

Comment: @ThePirateBay, could you show me where SSA is a theorem about congruence?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern. I'm not sure what you're asking. *"could you show me where SSA is a theorem about congruence?"* - what do you mean? You can prove the examples from the link I've posted using trigonometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side-side-angle fails when there are two or no solutions.  Your diagram presumably guarantees there is at least one solution.  You get two solutions if you draw a circle around $P$ with radius $NP$ and it hits the ray $MN$ in two places.  This is avoided if $NP \gt MP$ because the circle goes around behind $M$.  If $NP$ is less than $MP$ but not too much less, $O$ could be higher on the page making $\angle NPO$ acute and the triangles are not congruent.  If $NP$ is too much less than $MP$ the circle won't reach the ray and there is no solution.

Answer (score 5):

Even with a shared side, Side-Side-Angle —in and of itself— is not a congruence pattern. In your diagram, the relative positions of points $M$ and $O$ are ambiguous from the given information.

[image]

Comment: If it is not a secret, which program have you used to render that image?

Comment: @Math_974: No secret. It's [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org).